# How to get Map with condition using RxJava2 and RxAndroid?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

So, I have sorted by condition list of objects

```
private Observable<CallServiceCode> getUnansweredQuestionList() {
    return Observable.fromIterable(getServiceCodeArrayList())
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
               .filter(iServiceCode -> iServiceCode.getServiceCodeFormStatus().isUnanswered());
}
```

and now what I need to do:

Every object has list `servicePartList` , I need to filter this list by condition and eventually if final size of this filtered list `>0`, so I need to add object that contains this list `CallServiceCode object` as a key and this filtered list as a value.

So it should be like this:

```
private Map<CallServiceCode, ArrayList<CallServicePart>> getSortedMap() {
      Map<CallServiceCode, ArrayList<CallServicePart>> result = new HashMap<>();

      getUnansweredQuestionList()
          .filter(callServiceCode -> Observable.fromIterable(callServiceCode.getCallServicePartList()) //
          .filter(servicePart -> servicePart.getServicePartFormStatus().isUnanswered())//
          .isNotEmpty())
          .subscribe(callServiceCode -> result.put(callServiceCode, Observable.fromIterable(callServiceCode.getCallServicePartList()) //
                                                                                                .filter(servicePart -> servicePart.getServicePartFormStatus().isUnanswered()));
      return result;
}
```

But there is no such method `isNotEmpty()` in RxJava2 and also it is not right to add key like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(callServiceCode.getCallServicePartList())
    .filter(servicePart -> servicePart.getServicePartFormStatus().isUnanswered())
```

So question is how to make it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to use `collect` to create the `Map` directly from the observable:

```
return getUnansweredQuestionList()
        .collect(HashMap<CallServiceCode, List<CallServicePart>>::new,(hashMap, callServiceCode) -> {
            List<CallServicePart> callServiceParts = Observable.fromIterable(callServiceCode.getServicePartList())
                        .filter(s -> !s.getServicePartFormStatus().isUnanswered())
                        .toList().blockingGet();
            if (!callServiceParts.isEmpty())
                hashMap.put(callServiceCode, callServiceParts);
        }).blockingGet();
```

If you extract filtering into a method (could be also member of `CallServiceCode`) then the code is much cleaner:

```
return getUnansweredQuestionList()
           .collect(HashMap<CallServiceCode, List<CallServicePart>>::new, (hashMap, callServiceCode) -> {
               List<CallServicePart> filteredParts = getFilteredServiceParts(callServiceCode.getServicePartList());
               if (!filteredParts .isEmpty())
                   hashMap.put(callServiceCode, filteredParts);
            }).blockingGet();
```